# python or on operator module

Tags: python, operators

On the `operator` module, we have the `or_` function, [which is the bitwise or](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.or_) (`|`).

However I can't seem to find the logical or (`or`).

The documentation [doesn't seem to list it](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions).

I'm wondering why isn't it included? Is it not considered a operator?

Is there a builtin function that provides its behaviour?

Comment: Can you concoct a use-case where this hypothetical `operator.or2` would be useful or necessary?

Comment: "Is it not considered a operator?" I believe the answer to this question could be *no*, they are **not** normal operators. In Python you can override all operators via the so-called "magic methods", for example you can implement `__or__` to change the behaviour of `|` for your classes, but *there's no method that implements `or` and `and`*. These two operations require direct support by the interpreter in order to short-circuit the evaluation of the operands.

Comment: By the way: also the unary `not` is not a normal method in this sense because there's no `__not__` special method. You can only implement `__bool__` (or `__nonzero__` in python2) and when python executes `not` it explicitly negates the value returned by `__bool__`. However this function is provided by the `operator` module because it doesn't have short-circuiting behaviour.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `or` operator *short circuits*; the right-hand expression is not evaluated when the left-hand returns a true value. This applies to the `and` operator as well; when the left-hand side expression returns a false value, the right-hand expression is not evaluated.

You could not do this with a function; all operands *have* to be evaluated before the function can be called. As such, there is no equivalent function for it in the `operator` module.

Compare:

```
foo = None
result = foo and foo(bar)
```

with

```
foo = None
result = operator.boolean_and(foo, foo(bar))  # hypothetical and implementation
```

The latter expression will fail, because you cannot use `None` as a callable. The first version works, because the `and` operator won't evaluate the `foo(bar)` expression.

Comment: I don't think this really answers his question. I believe he was asking why doing `1 or 2` returns `1` instead of `True`.

Comment: @aruisdante: no, he is not. *On the operator module we have the `or_` function* ... *However I can't seem to find the logical or*.

Comment: @aruisdante: and *The documentation doesn't seem to list it. I'm wondering why isn't it included? Is it not considered a operator?*. I am not sure why you think this is about what the operator returns.

Comment: Mm, you are likely correct. I misread the OP's question based on his inclusion of return values. And I definitely agree with your explanation as to why you couldn't duplicate the functionality of `or` with a function. I feel better that I'm not the only one that was confused by it though :p

Comment: @aruisdante I included the return values to show they are the same function, but it seems it just made the question more confusing. I've edited it, hopefully it's clearer now

Answer (score 6):

The closest thing to a built-in `or` function is [any](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#any):

```
>>> any((1, 2))
True
```

If you wanted to duplicate `or`'s functionality of returning non-boolean operands, you could use [next](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#next) with a filter:

```
>>> next(operand for operand in (1, 2) if operand)
1
```

But like Martijn said, neither are true drop-in replacements for `or` because it short-circuits. A true `or` function would have to accept functions to be able to avoid evaluating all the results:

```
logical_or(lambda: 1, lambda: 2)
```

This is somewhat unwieldy, and would be inconsistent with the rest of the `operator` module, so it's probably best that it's left out and you use other explicit methods instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, I mentioned that in the third paragraph.

Comment: Just making it explicit. :-) But indeed, I missed the middle paragraph amidst all the huge posts explaining about the difference between `or` and `|`...

Comment: +1 for explaining potential alternatives

Answer (score 1):

### It's not possible:

[This can explicitly be found in the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations):

> The expression x or y first evaluates x; if x is true, its value is
>   returned; otherwise, y is evaluated and the resulting value is
>   returned.

It does not exist as an `operator` function because due to the language specification, it is impossible to implement because you cannot delay execution of a called argument when calling the function. Here is an example of `or` in action:

```
def foo():
    return 'foo'

def bar():
    raise RuntimeError
```

If bar is called, we get a Runtime error. And looking at the following line, we see that Python shortcuts the evaluation of the line, since `foo` returns a `True`-ish value.

```
>>> foo() or bar()
'foo'
```

### We can approximate:

We can simulate this behavior by passing in uncalled functions, and then calling them inside our `or` function:

```
def my_or(*funcs):
    for func in funcs:
        call = func()
        if call:
            return call
    return call

>>> my_or(foo, bar)
'foo'
```

But you *cannot* shortcut execution of called callables that are passed to a function:

```
>>> my_or(foo, bar())

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#28>", line 1, in <module>
    like_or(foo, bar())
  File "<pyshell#24>", line 2, in bar
    raise RuntimeError
RuntimeError
```

*So it would be improper to include such a function in the built-ins or standard library because users would expect an `or` function to work just as a boolean `or` test, which again, is impossible.*

Answer (score -2):

The reason you are getting `1` after executing `>>> 1 or 2` is because `1` is `true` so the expression has been satisfied.

It might make more sense if you try executing `>>> 0 or 2`. It will return `2` because the first statement is `0` or `false` so the second statement gets evaluated. In this case `2` evaluates to a `true` boolean value.

The `and` and `or` operators evaluate the first value and then plug the result into the "AND and OR" truth tables. In the case of `and` the second value is only considered if the first evaluates to `true`. In the case of the `or` operator, if the first value evaluates to `true` the expression is true and can return, if it isn't the second value is evaluated.

Comment: Do read the question carefully. This is **not** about how the `or` operator works. This is about the [`operator` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) not having a function equivalent of the operator for dynamic application.

Comment: @MartijnPieters My mistake, you're right, I didn't read his question properly.